# KDBG usage in volatility

Tags: forensics

I am using volatility recently and I noticed that it uses kdbgscan command, that is about kernel debugger block.
Can someone explain in plain words what is it and why are we using it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The KDBG is a structure maintained by the Windows kernel for debugging purposes. It contains a list of the running processes and loaded kernel modules. It also contains some version information that allows you to determine if a memory dump came from a Windows XP system versus Windows 7, what Service Pack was installed, and the memory model (32-bit vs 64-bit).